# How do I prevent content from going under the footer?

Tags: html, css

I am using `min-height: 200vw` and `position: relative` on my container div, and I have a footer inside of it using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`.  How can I prevent content from going under the footer, and make it push the footer down instead?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .content-text {
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 
 footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="content-text">Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main  </p>

  <footer>
    <p>Footer Content</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using absolute, so your footer is not in the flow of the page. You need to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, a simple way would be to give the container a `padding-bottom` equivalent to the height of the `footer`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
  /* added */
  padding-bottom: 10em;
}

.content-text {
  font-size: 2em;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p class="content-text">Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content...
    Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main content... Main </p>

  <footer>
    <p>Footer Content</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```